# Export Morris.js chart into PDF?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, morris.js

I have generated Morris.js Bar Chart using php and MySQL data. I want to now export the chart into PDF. Is there a way to do this? I am using `FPDF` library but I do not know how to do it.

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");

$chart_data = '';

$db = new dbObj();
$connString =  $db->getConnstring();
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query = $connString->prepare("SELECT ID, Name, Wrongs, Rights, Percentage, Age FROM Datas WHERE ID=?");
$query->bind_param('s',$id);
$query->execute();
$result=$query->get_result();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $chart_data .= "{ ID:'".$row["ID"]."', Wrongs:".$row["Wrongs"].", Rights:".$row["Rights"]." , Age:".$row["Age"]. ", Percentage:".$row["Percentage"]."},";

}
echo $chart_data;

$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> PHP & Mysql</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">MySQL</h2>
   <h3 align="center">Data</h3>   
   <br /><br />
   <div id="bar-chart" data-colors="#29abe2,#ffc142,#1ab394, #FF0000, #FFFF00" ></div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
var labelColor = jQuery('#bar-chart').css('color');
 Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-chart',
  data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
  xkey: 'ID',
  ykeys: ['Rights', 'Wrongs', 'Percentage', 'Age'],
  labels: ['Rights','Wrongs', 'Percentage', 'Age'],
  hideHover:true,
  gridTextColor: labelColor,
  barColors: jQuery('#bar-chart').data('colors').split(',')
 // yLabelFormat: function(y) {return y = Math.round(y);}
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: depends on how Morris works. If the JS creates simple html, than you could run it in an "virtual" browser and save the rendered html and use this for converting to an pdf. If not, or the generated code is somehow "special", this may not work reliable.

Comment: @MRonline no its nothing special other than displaying bar charts with values in it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using `html2canvas`. The script is given below. First we have to add `html2canvas` and `jspdf` library under html.

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.1/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Add a button to call.

```
<div id="chart"></div>
  <button id="save">Download</button>
```

Then, add this script after `Morris.Bar` chart

```
$("#save").click(function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('bar-chart')).then(canvas => {
        var w = document.getElementById("bar-chart").offsetWidth;
        var h = document.getElementById("bar-chart").offsetHeight;

        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);

        var doc = new jsPDF('L', 'pt', [w, h]);
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, w, h);
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
})
```